# Mousedown and Up not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used mouseup/down/move to manually implement jQuery.draggable functionality. Everything was working fine until I tried to move my `div` inside a jQuery popup window.

After moving the div

```
dialogOpenMultiple("Title", "1234", "<div id=\"include\"></div>");
$('.autosize').appendTo('#include');
```

I faced two problems:

1. Firstly, the cursor is not moving bellow my mouse cursor because of some issue with offset and pageX, pageY.
2. While mousemove is working mouseup / drag / mousedown is not working because of the default browser's functionality  which selects and tries to move the actual picture.

Please look the not working sample here:

### - [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ntenisOT/aGH3D/3/)

Working sample:

### - [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ntenisOT/aGH3D/4/)

Comment: For me the not working sample works (but the input boxes don't) and the working sample does not work (but the input boxes do)

Comment: Uh, either FF3.6 or Opera 10.10 on Mac OS X 10.4.11. Now I'm using FF9 on Windows 7 and... same thing.

Comment: With FF8 in Ubuntu is working just fine. Really strange. I will check it tomorrow. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated fiddle showing working draggable.

http://jsfiddle.net/NMpwU/1/

added e.preventDefault(); to mousedown function and changed the if (newdiv == null) to if (newdiv === null)

Comment: Can I somehow fix the position of the cursor as well?

Answer (score 1):

1)  Easily fixed using cursor css.  This will give a much better user experience.  `cursor:url(linkCursor.png), pointer;`

2)  You can stop browser default actions by adding `e.preventDefault()` to your events.

Comment: Where I have to put the css ?

Comment: the cursor css is added to any css selector, if the cursor is hovering over that area it will be applied.